# Unable to reach network namespace through master

Tags: networking, ping, namespaces, network-namespace

I'm trying to create an isolated lab using network namespaces.
It works correctly, that is, only the machines in the network namespace can talk.
But now I want reach the machines by localhost using v-net-0 like a router.

Here what i do:

```sh
ip netns add red
ip netns add blue
ip link add v-net-0 type bridge
ip link set dev v-net-0 up
ip link add veth-red type veth peer name veth-red-br
ip link add veth-blue type veth peer name veth-blue-br
ip link set veth-red netns red
ip link set veth-blue netns blue
ip link set veth-red-br master v-net-0
ip link set veth-blue-br master v-net-0
ip -n red addr add 192.168.15.2/24 dev veth-red
ip -n blue addr add 192.168.15.3/24 dev veth-blue
ip -n red link set veth-red up
ip -n blue link set veth-blue up
```

Here everything is ok, the two virtual interfaces can communicate with each other in a totally isolated way

But now from the localhost I want to be able to reach the two virtual interfaces using the `v-net-0` to make this i assign at the `v-net-0` an ip.

```sh
ip addr add 192.168.15.5/24 dev v-net-0
```

So the localhost can ping the `v-net-0` but red and blue are unreachable.
What i can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Linux bridge (brctl) or openvswitch to connect multiple ns in the same VLAN.

See also:

- https://josedonizetti.github.io/cni/namespace/bridge/linux/network/2017/10/22/container-networking-bridge.html
- https://www.opencloudblog.com/?p=66
- https://lwn.net/Articles/580893/

Comment: I just connect multiple ns in the same VLAN, the problem is that i can reach the master from the localhost but the master doesn't route the traffic to the other namespace.

Comment: The NS are connected between themselves, but not with the host. You need to add a connection as you already did with veth for ns.

Answer (score 0):

Use ‘ipvlan’ you’ll have 192.168.15.x in default/red/blue ns.